# Read Certificates of Host and output it to Splunk

Tags: powershell, ssl-certificate

i got block in my brain and don`t know how to fix ist.

i have following script:

```html
$CorrelationId = New-Guid
$Server = Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem| Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
$getcert= Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\My -Recurse | Where-Object {$_ -is [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2] -and ($_.NotAfter -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(45)) -and($_.Issuer -eq "CN=test.at, DC=ds, DC=test, DC=at")}  | Select-Object -Property Issuer, NotAfter, Subject, FriendlyName


$notafter = $getcert.NotAfter
$Subject = $getcert.Subject
$issuer = $getcert.Issuer
$FriendlyName= $getcert.FriendlyName


Write-Log -D Console,Splunk -L Info -A Servercertificate -M " Certificate $Subject on Host $Server with issuer $issuer and FriendlyName $FriendlyName expires at $notafter" -CorrelationId $CorrelationId -EventId 1
```

as long i have just 1 Cert it works proper, but if i got more than one it`s just wired.

I know that it is may possible to fix this with foreach, but i don`t know how to do it.

Thanks for your Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `Write-Log` command is working as expected, and you'd prefer to have a unique CorrelationId per certificate, then it should be fairly straightforward.

For example:

```
$Server = Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem| Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
$getcert= Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\My -Recurse | Where-Object {$_ -is [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2] -and ($_.NotAfter -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(45)) -and ($_.Issuer -eq "CN=test.at, DC=ds, DC=test, DC=at")}  | Select-Object -Property Issuer, NotAfter, Subject, FriendlyName

foreach ($cert in $getcert) {
    $CorrelationId = New-Guid

    $notafter = $cert.NotAfter
    $Subject = $cert.Subject
    $issuer = $cert.Issuer
    $FriendlyName = $cert.FriendlyName

    Write-Log -D Console,Splunk -L Info -A Servercertificate -M " Certificate $Subject on Host $Server with issuer $issuer and FriendlyName $FriendlyName expires at $notafter" -CorrelationId $CorrelationId -EventId 1
}
```